# for-loop in Bash Script Exits After Processing First Line

Tags: bash, for-loop, scripting

Running this in terminal runs fine:

```
for a in *.pdf; do mv "$a" "$a".tmp; done
```

Running this inside a bash script (`#!/bin/bash`)

```
for a in "$1"; do mv "$a" "$a".tmp; done
```

...and passing the parameter `*.pdf`, i.e. `./myscript *.pdf`, the script processes **only the first file** in the directory. Testing by changing `mv` to `echo` shows the same thing.

Any explanation why this is so, and how I could make it work to process all file matches? Thanks!

Comment: the shell will already expand the `*.pdf` and pass in the list of pdfs to myscript. if you want to pass the string `*.pdf` to your script you will have to quote or escape it. `./myscript "*.pdf"` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$1` is only the first argument (here the first pdf). To loop through all the arguments, use:

```
for var in "$@"; do
   do mv "$var" "$var".tmp
done
```

`$@` is a bash built-in variable, an array containing all the command-line parameters. So you know, there is also `$*`, which is :

> All of the positional parameters, seen as a single word ([src](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html))

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you run

```
./myscript *.pdf
```

first thing that happens, is that `*.pdf` gets expanded to all matches. So what you actually call is

```
./myscript file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf
```

Try

```
for a; do
    mv "$a" "$a".tmp
done
```

This will loop over all positional arguments.